# Calculating the total of an online order form using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a basic order form and I would like to see if I can build it from stratch.

I have a form which is made up of a table with 12 items listed and text input fields for item quantity. What I would like to do is have the code run through the form to check for any quantities that have been entered, then relate these values to the prices in an array.

So far I have the array:

```
var juicePrice = new Array();
juicePrice["citrusZing"]=20.00;
juicePrice["strawberrySmooth"]=22.00;
juicePrice["carrotSpin"]=21.50;
juicePrice["Tropical"]=20.75;
...
```

and a way to run through the form:

```
calculateTotal()    
{   
var juiceForm = document.forms["juiceform"];

    //Get a reference to the juice the user Chooses name=selectedJuiceQty":
    var selectedJuiceQty = juiceForm.elements["selectedJuiceQty"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedJuiceQty.length; i++);
```

but I'm not quite sure how to connect the information from the form to calculate the totals. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is it something like this?

```
for(var i = 0; i < selectedJuiceQty.length; i++){
    var juiceTotal = 0;

    if(selectedJuiceQty[i]>0) {
        juiceTotal += juicePrice[selectedJuiceQty[i].value]*selectedJuiceQty;
        //If we get a match then we break out of this loop
        break;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Is it possible to use the same name tag for each field or should I just use `citrusZingQty = parseInt(document.getElementById("citrusZing").value);` for each item? Then I would have to list all of the items, which doesn't seem a very elegant way. What would happen if multiple items are selected?

Any help anyone can give to point me in the right direction would be great.

Comment: For an assignment, so I guess yes. Will that affect the answer?

Comment: Note that although you declared an array, you are adding object properties to it.  JavaScript dont work like PHP associative arrays or hashes in other languages! They don't have string keys!.  `var juicePrice = {};` ... to declare as an object, since that's how you're using it.

Comment: *“Will that affect the answer?”* – Many will try to give hints rather than just correct solutions when a question is tagged as homework so that you can actually try to come up with the solution yourself and learn something without seeing just the solution.

Comment: @user1361276 This question shows serious effort already, so you will get help. homework questions that arrive with no evidence of effort get closed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Michael. We weren't given very much information on arrays. I'm trying to learn as much as I can from anywhere I can...

Comment: Are you required to use javascript to do te calculations? Doing the order form calculations via JavaScript is not recommended. This is because the user can modif any stuff in JavaScript and can rven change the cost to 0 and buy everything without paying. You should probably use AJAX for all the calculations do that the user cannot modify them.

Comment: We are meant to use JavaScript, but we wouldn't be penalised if we use some AJAX. How would the user be able to modify the JavaScript? Sorry, I am quite new to JavaScript so I don't know all the tricks.

Comment: @user1361276, Any client side information, including textboxes , javascripts, cookies etc can be tempered with easily available tools so the financial calculations that can cost your company are not kept or dealt with on client side, but since this is an assignment you can continue using JS, but never try such code in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can do what you want.  Michael pointed this out in the comments but it may have been overlooked.

```
var myPrices = new Object();
myPrices['eggs'] = 1.50;
myPrices['bread'] = 1.00;
// ...
```

Then you can loop through your form fields and check against your 'myPrices' object.

EDIT

To answer your question in the comments - I would not use the same name for all of my input fields.  It does make looping through the form easier perhaps.  However, using the id/class of the input tag is not a nice solution in my opinion.  HTML id/class are there for CSS/Javascript manipulation and using it to identify which fruit the input represents will not be apparent to other developers working on the project (I realize this may be a small project for you but it's best not to start any bad habits).  I would name each input after the juice/drink it represents.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. Would it be OK for me to use the same name attribute for each field? Would it create problems if more than one item is selected?

Comment: You mean the names of the form fields?  Can you add the HTML for what you mean to your question?

Comment: yes, in the form fields. if for example I gave each quantity field a name like `name="juiceqty"`, will it present problems?

Comment: I don't think that's a "problem" necessarily - but how will you link the first one to orange juice, the second to grape juice, etc.?

Comment: I'm not sure... The only way I can think if is to use their id, but I was wondering if there is a 'neater' way...

Comment: Thanks @jeff, you are right, I don't want to get into any bad habits while I'm still learning.
So, if I give each input field a unique name, then loop through the form and add a series of ifs 

e.g. `var juiceTotal = 0;

if (citrusZing>0)
{
JuiceTotal+=(citrusZing*juicePrice[0]);
}...`
   
Could that work in terms of checking against my prices list? 
How would I add all the subtotals to the list? Would i need to just add each subtotal sequentially?

Comment: Okay, i'll give you an overall idea - you will loop through your form's inputs.  You will use the name to lookup the corresponding price and calculate the subtotal as you did in your example.  however, you can do the entire thing in a for loop without the need to hard code citrusZing, etc.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes

Comment: Thanks @jeff, I'm actually getting somewhere now :-). I want to put in a statement which ignores an input field if it is left blank. I wrote: 
`if (juiceForm[i].value == 0 || isNaN(juiceForm[i].value))
{
juiceForm[i].value == 0;
}`
   
It works if the input is 0, but not if the field is left blank. Do you have any tips/hints?

Comment: If you are not acquainted with debuggers - another good way to figure out what is going on is to drop a print (maybe alert() in javascript).  Alert the value and see what you get.  Also I would recommend checking isNaN first b/c it doesn't make sense to check for == 0 if the input is not a number.  Good luck.

Comment: I have posted what I have so far in an edit. Does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the tips. I have just about got the form working how I want it